# Spring gets Null values from Retrofit

Tags: java, android, spring, retrofit

I am trying to send POST Request from Android to Spring via Retrofit from past 2 days. I have tried plenty of solutions regarding this, but nothing seems to be working. So, asking here finally to be able to get some help.

So, i am trying to send a simple Object from Android to Spring via retrofit. From android side i have verified the values sent by me and it gives me correct value.(I have debugged it via Android's debugging mode). But on spring side i got null values.

This is my code ->

**function foo() -> from which i am sending my request.**

```
 private void foo() {
            request.setName1("XYZ");
            request.setName2("PQR");
            Api.upload(request, new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Success" + response.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Failure");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**my upload Function ->**

```
public static void upload(Request request, Callback<BasicResponse> callback) {
        uploadRequest api = retrofit.create(uploadRequest.class);
        Call<BasicResponse> call = uploadRequest.uploadCall(POJO);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

**This is my UploadRequest Interface ->**

```
 public interface uploadRequest{
        @POST(UPLOAD_REQUEST)
        Call<BasicResponse> uploadCall(@Body POJO pojo);
    }
```

**This is My POJO Class**

```
public class POJO {

    private String Name1;
    private String Name2;

    public String getName1() {
        return Name1;
    }

    public void setName1(String name1) {
        Name1 = name1;
    }

    public String getName2() {
        return Name2;
    }

    public void setName2(String name2) {
        Name2 = name2;
    }
}
```

**And this is my Spring Controller Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UploadRequest",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public void UploadImage(@RequestBody POJO pojo,HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(pojo!=null){
            System.out.println("pojo is not null");
            System.out.println(pojo.getName1());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("null");
        }
}
```

**I am getting pojo is not null and inside the pojo.getName1(), the value prints is null.**

Edit : Adding BasicResponse Class.

```
public class BasicResponse {

    private boolean success = Boolean.TRUE;
    private ErrorCode errorCode;
    private String response;
    private Integer totalCount;
    private String callingUserId;

    public BasicResponse() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public ErrorCode getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(ErrorCode errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.success = false;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Object response) {
        if (response != null) {
            this.response = GsonUtils.toGson(response);
        }
    }

    public Integer getTotalCount() {
        return totalCount;
    }

    public void setTotalCount(Integer totalCount) {
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }

    public String getCallingUserId() {
        return callingUserId;
    }

    public void setCallingUserId(String callingUserId) {
        this.callingUserId = callingUserId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of response?

Comment: @tm13 on spring side it's printing pojo is not null and null, which means that pojo object received by my code is not null/

Answer (score 1):

Compare the response and your POJO class. The instance variables of your POJO class must be the same as in response. In your case Name1 and Name2. If they are name1, name2 in the response (which means if they do not start with capital letters, etc.), or different, it gives you `NullPointerException`.

Comment: So, you are saying that the my BasicResponse and POJO class should be the same? If you are saying that the POJO class on Android side and Spring side should be the same then they are same.

Comment: Can you comment or edit your answer to show one example of your JSON response? It would be more clear

Comment: Basic Response is just a class with Method that returns String that one whats to return. @tm13 added BasicResponse class.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Name1 and Name2 have different names in json than in your POJO and Jackson, with is used under the hood when you annotate your parameters with @RequestBody can not figure them out, so you get null values. Check out your json.

Comment: i am using gson, not Jsckson. can you tell me how can i check my JSON on Spring side?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/UploadRequest",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public void UploadImage(@RequestBody String pojo,HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(pojo);
}

Comment: Sorry for formatting, but you propably get the idea

Comment: I have Returned the POJO class with  basicResponse.setResponse(cropImageRequest); and it returns {} "Empty JSON", however i have also provided the method to check if object is null or not inside UploadImage Function, and in that function it's not null. :(